# Feature - Documentation when flagging the question

Tags: feature-request

Every question on SO, below the tags have three options:
- share
- edit
- flag

It would be beneficial to include a fourth option named: - documentation

Many times there are questions, that already have an answer in the documentation. I see the question, and instead of replying with copy/paste code, I could point the user to the documentation which already contains the answer, by selecting appropriate document.

Comment: You actually have the option to answer a question, which you left out for some reason

Comment: I changed it ti be more precise.

Comment: Oh! sorry, now I understand. FYI - when you have more reputation you  also have the option to  _close_, _delete_ and _protect_ a question. I still don't have enough reputation to protect a question so I don't see this option